# Axes Permutation using Numpy transpose gives unexpected results

Tags: python, numpy, transpose

Yelo!

This is my understanding of `np.transpose(arr, perm_pos)`:

Say we want to move axes of a 3D `np.ndarray` to specific positions in the transposed `ndarray`, we essentially specify the `perm_pos` to the target axes indices. For Eg.:

```
a = np.arange(100).reshape((2, 10, 5))
target_shape = (5, 2, 10)
print(f"Explicit shape transform: {a.transpose((1, 2, 0)).shape}")  # prints the target shape as above.
```

So far so good!

Now consider the following example:

```
# bigger example 
b = np.arange(239400).reshape((126, 380, 5))
target_shape_ = (5, 126, 380)
print(f"Explicit shape transform: {b.transpose((1, 2, 0)).shape}")  # prints  a different shape from the desired target_shape
```

Why's this going wrong?

I do know that I could simply use `np.moveaxis` function to bring `axis 3` to position `0` by np.moveaxis(b, -1, 0), but that is not something I wish to do. What's happening here?

Cheers!

**EDIT**

Apologies for having misunderstood the function parameters.
Yes, indeed the above code doesn't yield the target shape desired.
Setting the `perm_pos` to `(2, 0, 1)` will yield the desired target_shape.

Comment: Are you sure you got the correct code? `a.transpose((1, 2, 0)).shape` gives me `(10, 5, 2)`, not `(5,2,10)`, which is expected. You want `.transpose(2,0,1).shape`.

Comment: (1,2,0) moves the first dimension to the end.

Comment: Ah shoot Right! I've got the transpose axes order wrong! the perm_pos specifies the axis position after transpose! and not move it to the specified position! My bad!

Answer (score 1):

When I try this, I don't get the specified order in both cases. Instead, I get (10, 5, 2) and (380, 5, 126). If you change (1, 2, 0) to (2, 0, 1) in both cases, it works as expected, so there is no difference between the small and the big example.

Answer (score 0):

Let me clearly explain how to calculate permutation argument: in your example, you want to transpose an array of size (a,b,c) into (a,c,b). To calculate the permutation argument, first you must number each axis pythonically, so in given example: "a" is axis=0, "b" is axis =1, and "c" is axis=2. Then, you should **maintain** original axis numbers and arrange **those numbers** into final desired axes arrangement, as in: a should be placed in axis=1 and "a" **was** represented by number 0 so 0 sits in position of axis=1 which gives => ( ?, 0, ?), and by maintaining the same condition for other axes the permutation argument of (2,0,1) will be obtained. However, It is easy to mistake final axis numbers instead of the original ones in calculating the permutation argument, like mistakenly considering: "a" should become axis=1, "b" should become axis=2, and "c" should become axis=0, which gives wrong value of (1,2,0). In some cases, even if you choose the second method (the wrong one) you might end up getting the right answer if arrangement change is symmetrical from point of view of a middle axis which splits axes equally (in 3 dimension it is axis=1 but for example in 4 dimension it is an imaginary axis between axis=1 and axis=2), for example if you want to reshape (a, b, c) into (c,b,a), both methods yield permutation argument of (2, 1, 0). So, it is easy to think your wrong method is right and wonder why it does not work for some specific reshapes!